# training apriori dataset with pandas not displaying results

Tags: python, pandas

I have created dataframe and list  according to the apriori algorithms, I have created rules as well. but the results are not coming out and it's also not showing any error.

below is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('itemlist.csv', header = None)


togetheritems = []
for i in range(0, 2071):
    togetheritems.append([str(df.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 53)])

# Training Apriori on the dataset

from apyori import apriori
rules = apriori(togetheritems, min_support = 0.002, min_confidence = 0.1, min_lift = 2, min_length = 4)

rules = [list(results[i][0]) for i in range(0,len(results))]

# Visualising the results
results = list(rules)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't asked Python to visualise the results you've just assigned them to a variable. Try `print(results)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried, but i am not getting result variable as well. it just stuck, no error nothing..

Comment: When you say it's stuck do you mean it's taking a long time to execute? Or does it exit in some way?